How can I refurbish this vanity countertop?
I am remodeling my apartment. In the sink there are cracks. I don't want to spend the money to install a new sink, so how do I fix the cracks and refurbish this vanity?

What should I use to fill up the cracks?   What type of glue should I use? Can I use Bondo?

How can I refurbish this countertop?

What type of paint do I need to paint it?




Generally speaking, you don't paint a sink. You replace it.
That said, the same kind of coatings you might use in a shower could work here. Showers don't take as much abuse a sinks, so I have doubts that it'll be a long-term solution.
You could also look at local unclaimed freight or salvaged good stores for an inexpensive replacement.

If you are remodeling plan on a new sink. If you have to, cut other things from the budget.
Refinishing will cost more than a new sink.
Applying a sealer to the cracks will look like an amateurish bandage on an old item in a new remodel. If it should fail you risk water damage to the cabinet, floor and possibly more.  I don't think this approach is worth the risk.
To help fit a sink in your budget, try shopping at Habitat-for-Humanity stores or other salvage or discount home supply stores. A new or slightly used vanity may need a coat of paint to match your decor, but the price can be surprising.
(Last week I found a 48" new vanity with counter and built-in sink for $115. solid wood with dovetail drawers!)

Hope you picked it up.

Idk what planet you live on but in Canada they dont have habitat for humanity, I searched all over, and there are few that are the same size dimensions

And how would anyone know you are in Canada, since you didn't mention where in he world you are in your post.
